# Using Primary Key on Table Variable to improve seek performance

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, table-variable

I have this table variable I use in my SP:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier)
```

Then I insert some data into it (I later use):

```
INSERT INTO @t(ID)
SELECT ID FROM Categories WHERE ...
```

And later I have a few `SELECT` and `UPDATE` based on `@t` IDs e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories A INNER JOIN @t T ON A.ID = T.ID

etc..
```

Should I declare `ID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY` to increase permanence in the `SELECT` / `UPDATE` statements?
If yes should it be clustered or non clustered?
What is the advised option in my case?

*EDIT:* All my tables in the DB have `uniqueidentifier` (ID) column as a primary key `NONCLUSTERED`

<strike>*EDIT2 :* Strangely (or not) when I tried to use `PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED` on the table variable, when using joined SELECT I see in the execution plan that there is a `Table Scan` on `@t`. but when I omit `NONCLUSTERED` there is a `Clustered Index Scan`.</strike>

Comment: So, all tables in your database have a GUID column as a primary key (and clustered index)?

Comment: I have asked myself this question many times before and I found out (speed tests) that the answer depends on many factors including the size of the table(s) involved, the structure of the other tables involved (is the joining column indexed), and other factors. I'd very much recommend that you do these speed tests with and without PK and also try using temp tables as suggested by @Jaco. Yet, I would never dare giving an answer to that question as it all depends: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386

Comment: @IvanStarostin, my tables in the DB have GUID column as a primary key NONCLUSTERED

Comment: @zig, how big is @t and what join operator is used in plan: loops/hash? you'd better post actual execution plan in your question.

Comment: @Ivan, `@t` could be around 1 to 100 records. My edit regarding the execution plan was not accurate. it seems that only when I add more columns to `@t` (other than ID) NONCLUSTERED has no effect or I might be reading the plan wrong...

Comment: Any kind of index will have no sense since whole table fits one page. The only point for performance tuning could be the way it is used.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, "The only point for performance tuning could be the way it is used" meaning creating only ID column for the table variable?

Comment: meaning: *what is actual execution plan*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are worried about performance, you should probably not be using a table variable, but  use a temporary table instead. The problem with table variables is that statements referencing it are compiled when the table is empty and therefore the query optimiser always assumes there is only one row. This can result in suboptimal performance when the table variable is populated with many more rows.

Regarding the primary key, there are downsides to make the primary clustered as it will result in the table being physically ordered by the index. The overhead of this sorting operation may outweigh the performance benefit when querying the data. In general it is better to add a non-clustered index, however, as always, it will depend on your particular problem and you will have to test the different implementations.